# How do I define the TypeScript of onBeforeInputCapture in input element(React)?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, onchange, html-input

I use onBeforeInputCapture to get value when I copy and paste a string to an input JSX element.My purpose is to detect the modification in the input value.
I set its type to e:FormEvent, and try to get value by e.data, but vs code keeps on warning me "Property 'data' does not exist on type 'FormEvent"
I'm pretty sure there has a property in onBeforeInputCapture event, since if I set e:any, it can get the value from e.data.

[CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/still-haze-o5by5b?file=/src/App.tsx:101-196)

Code below shows what I'v tried.If I set the typescript of an event to any, it can get the changing value of the input JSX element.However, any is not allowed to use in this project.But when I try to set its typescript to FormEvent, it warns me that 'Property 'data' does not exist on type 'FormEvent''.

I also tried to console.log(event) to see if there's 'data' property, and it surely has it!But why typescript says there's no 'data' property in 'FormEvent'?

```
import "./styles.css";
import { FormEvent } from 'react'

export default function App() {
  //fail
  const beforeInputCaptureHandler=(event:FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>)=>{
    console.log(event.data)

  }

  //success but not prefer
  // const beforeInputCaptureHandler=(event:any)=>{
  //   console.log(event.data)
  // }

  return (
    <div className="App">
    <input onBeforeInputCapture={beforeInputCaptureHandler} />
    </div>
  );
}
```